# Why is the fb.LogoutUser function not redirecting to the URL I'm telling it?

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, sdk

```
function fbLogoutUser() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response && response.status === 'connected') {

      FB.logout(function(response) {
          document.location.reload();
          top.location.href = 'url here';
      });

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
      {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          document.location.reload();
          top.location.href = 'url here';
          });
      }
});}
```

Where it says 'url here', the browser acts like it attempts to load this page, but then never gets there.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are reloading the current location for both expected response statuses.  Did you want to reload the current location or redirect?

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
    document.location.reload();  // reload of current location here
    top.location.href = 'url here'; 
});
```

You can see how the redirect never occurs here: https://jsfiddle.net/jhend2099/35vbfbd9/

Comment: I want to redirect, but another answer I read indicated I should reload first to let Facebook know the user was confirmed logged out.

Comment: Once you reload, you're making a new request to the server.  It's going to reload the current page (or attempt to) after logout.  You could eliminate the reload and warn the user that they have been logged out and are about to be redirected to a new page.  

If you must stay on the current page, add a hidden field to indicate the "logged in" status and then, if logged out, indicate on the page that the user is logged out and redirect after a few seconds.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the reload, but the browser still fails to redirect after logout. It simply adds a "?" at the end of the original URL and then does not go anywhere.

Comment: You could try to use the [FB.Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.3) method.  You will need to subscribe to the event prior to logout.  (It can't be part of the FB logout callback.)

Something like:

`FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function() {window.location.hef = 'url here'});`

Comment: I tried that as well earlier, but with the same results. Although, what do you mean by '/logout'? Is that a placeholder for a page I have, or something to do with Facebook's backend?